# Possible to change dynamic libc.so address?

Tags: linux, gcc, ld

The commands

```
gcc main.c -o main
ldd main
```

yield

```
linux-gate.so.1 => (0x00f67000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00b7d000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00ae5000)
```

Is it possible to change the address where libc.so.6 will be mapped in memory? For example, have libc.so.6 instead be mapped at, say, 0xb0000000.

I'm running Xubuntu 32bit: Linux 3.2.0-23-generic i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: Why do you ask? Read also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: In order to perform a few ret2libc buffer overflow exploits, the payload string has to contain the addresses of a few libc functions that are not present in the plt section of my binary. This string should not contain any \x00 bytes, hence why I would like to have the libc library higher up in memory. Note that this is just a custom 'training binary'. ASLR has temporarily been disabled on my system (it's just a virtual machine for this sole purpose, so there's no harm in it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `prelink` utility ([wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prelink)) which is capable of changing loading address (it is called "base address") of so libs.

There is some info about how prelink works: [http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~charngda/elf.html](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/%7Echarngda/elf.html)

> What does this prelink do? It changes the base address of a dynamic library to the actual address in the user program's address space when it is loaded into memory. Of course, ld.so recognizes GNU_PRELINKED tag and will load a dynamic library to its this base address (recall the first argument of mmap is the preferred address; of course, this is subject to the operating system.)
>
> Normally, a dynamic library is built as position independent code, i.e. the -fPIC compiler command-line option, and thus the base address is 0. For example, a normal libc.so has ELF program header as follows (`readelf -l` command)...

According to [`man prelink`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/prelink) there is an option of prelink utility to rebase (relocate) given library to specified address:

> `-r --reloc-only=ADDRESS`
> Instead of prelinking, just relink given shared libraries to the specified base address.

The `prelink --reloc-only=0x7896000 libc.so.6` should be enough to achieve the change you want.

PS: you can do this relocation on your local copy of libc and then give the path to it via `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/rebased/copy:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`